# preg_match and preg_replace in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a task to find and replace words starting and ending with "#".

Example - my string will look like:

> Put your hands up in the air for #performer1# , Put your hands up in the air for #event#.

What I expect as a output is:

> Put your hands up in the air for **#performer1#** , Put your hands up in the air for **#event#**.

I have no idea about regular expressions in php, and I'm a beginner, can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already suggested, the [preg_replace function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) should do the trick. What you now need is a regular expression like this

```
$string = "Put your hands up in the air for #performer#, ...";
$pattern = "/#(\w+)#/";
$replacement = '<strong>$1</strong>';
$new_string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

The magic bit is the `$pattern` variable where you specify what to look for. If you put parenthesis around something, you can reference the actual contents in the `$replacement` variable.

The `\w+` basically says: match as many characters as possible (and at least one) that are either `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` or `_`.

The [PHP PCRE Pattern Syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) can give you some more hints about how to use regular expressions.